# writing in memory after reserving and committing memory using virtualAlloc

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++. I have written a c++ code (Visual Basic c++) which reserves and commits memory using virtual alloc following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . 
Now my problem is that i need to write the whole page that i have with a certain pattern 'a'.Should i use for loop or memcopy or memmove ?
I have used GetSystemInfo to get the page size which is obviously 4096. How can i do it. Do i have to modify this chunk?

```
for (i=0; i < PAGELIMIT*dwPageSize; i++)
{
    __try
    {
        // Write to memory.

        lpPtr[i] = 'a';
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know how to fill a buffer of memory with a particular value, you probably shouldn't be using `VirtualAlloc` (instead use `malloc`/`free`).

Answer (score 0):

Neither `memcpy` or `memmove` seems well suited to the task at hand.

Obvious choices would be `memset`, `std::fill`, `std::fill_n`, or a `for` loop.

Of those, `memset` works if and only if you want to fill the memory with `char`-sized items. Personally, I'd probably use `std::fill_n`.

Comment: ok i will look into memset and std::fill_n, never used it before.